# JSON from api to html

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am pulling json from an API but its format is not familiar to me.

It looks like this:

```
{"ok": true, "database": "boe_spending", "query_name": null, "rows": [["CITIBANK NA", 99237716.31], ["MARYLAND STATE RETIREMENT & PENSION SYSTEM", 16438857.25], ["DALY COMPUTERS INC", 9314951.79]], "truncated": false, "columns": ["payee_name_refined", "total"], "query": {"sql": "select payee_name_refined, sum(amount) as total\r\nfrom vendors \r\nwhere agency_name = 'ALLEGANY COUNTY PUBLIC SCHOOLS'\r\ngroup by 1\r\norder by 2 desc\r\nlimit 10", "params": {}}, "error": null, "private": false, "allow_execute_sql": true, "query_ms": 7.000529003562406}
```

I want to display the data in "rows" in HTML using javascript.

I am used to seeing JSON formatted like this (and I would know how to print it in my HTML):

```
[
    {
        "payee_name_refined": "CITIBANK NA",
        "sum": "99237716.31"
    },
    {
        "payee_name_refined": "MARYLAND STATE RETIREMENT & PENSION SYSTEM",
        "sum": "16438857.25"
    },
    {
        "payee_name_refined": "DALY COMPUTERS INC",
        "sum": "9314951.79"
    }
]
```

But I don't know what to do with the data I get from the API.

Ultimately, I'd like to print the following in HTML:

CITIBANK NA, $99,237,716.31

MARYLAND STATE RETIREMENT & PENSION SYSTEM, $16,438,857.25

DALY COMPUTERS INC, $9,314,951.79

How can I use the provided JSON data to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
const data = {"ok": true, "database": "boe_spending", "query_name": null, "rows": [["CITIBANK NA", 99237716.31], ["MARYLAND STATE RETIREMENT & PENSION SYSTEM", 16438857.25], ["DALY COMPUTERS INC", 9314951.79]], "truncated": false, "columns": ["payee_name_refined", "total"], "query": {"sql": "select payee_name_refined, sum(amount) as total\r\nfrom vendors \r\nwhere agency_name = 'ALLEGANY COUNTY PUBLIC SCHOOLS'\r\ngroup by 1\r\norder by 2 desc\r\nlimit 10", "params": {}}, "error": null, "private": false, "allow_execute_sql": true, "query_ms": 7.000529003562406};

// Iterate over this as you normally would with what you're used to working with
data.rows
// Assuming that you're iterating as "item"
// This is your 'payee_name_refined'
item[0]
// This is your 'sum'
item[1]

// Such as...
for (const item of data.rows) {
    // payee_name_refined
    console.log(item[0]);
    // sum
    console.log(item[1]);
}
```

Or transform it to your usual format...

```
const transformedData = data.rows.map(item => ({
    payee_name_refined: item[0], sum: item[1]
}));
```

And then work with it in the way that you're used to.

Answer (score -2):

`[]` is a syntax for array

```js
const data = {"ok": true, "database": "boe_spending", "query_name": null, "rows": [["CITIBANK NA", 99237716.31], ["MARYLAND STATE RETIREMENT & PENSION SYSTEM", 16438857.25], ["DALY COMPUTERS INC", 9314951.79]], "truncated": false, "columns": ["payee_name_refined", "total"], "query": {"sql": "select payee_name_refined, sum(amount) as total\r\nfrom vendors \r\nwhere agency_name = 'ALLEGANY COUNTY PUBLIC SCHOOLS'\r\ngroup by 1\r\norder by 2 desc\r\nlimit 10", "params": {}}, "error": null, "private": false, "allow_execute_sql": true, "query_ms": 7.000529003562406}

const container = document.querySelector('pre')

for (const row of data.rows) {
  container.textContent += row[0] + ' ' + row[1] + '\n'
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Good answers include some explanation alongside code